# HTML/CSS: empty page + only header page when printing table

Tags: html, css, printing

I cannot understand why there's a blank page + a page with only the table header in this document.

[image]

The rest is OK but I cannot get rid of these 2 pages.

This is the full HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <style media="print" type="text/css">

h1:not(:first-child) {
    page-break-before: always;
}

table {
    page-break-before : avoid;
    page-break-inside : avoid;
    padding: 0;border-collapse: collapse; }
table tr {
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #f8f8f8; }
table tr th {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 13px; }
table tr td {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 13px; }
table tr th :first-child, table tr td :first-child {
    margin-top: 0; }
table tr th :last-child, table tr td :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; }


tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after : avoid;
} 

th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after : avoid;
} 

p { orphans: 5; widows: 5; page-break-after: avoid; page-break-before: avoid; }

body {
    height: auto;
   font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.6;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 30px; 
}


body > *:first-child {
   margin-top: 0 !important; }
body > *:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0 !important; }

a {
   color: #4183C4; }
a.absent {
   color: #cc0000; }
a.anchor {
   display: block;
   padding-left: 30px;
   margin-left: -30px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   margin: 20px 0 10px;
   padding: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   cursor: text;
   position: relative; }

 body{counter-reset: section;}
   h2{counter-reset: sub-section;}
   h4{counter-reset: detail;}
   h3{counter-reset: composite;}
   h5{counter-reset: sub-detail;}

  h1{
     text-align:center;
     font-size:1.6em;
     margin-bottom: 10mm;
   }
   h2:before{
     counter-increment: section;
     content: counter(section) ". ";
   }
   h3:before{
     counter-increment: sub-section;
     content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) ". ";
   }
   h4:before{
     counter-increment: composite;
     content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) ". ";
   }
   h5:before{
     counter-increment: detail;
     content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) "." counter(detail) ". ";
   }
   h6:before{
     counter-increment: sub-detail;
     content: counter(section) "." counter(sub-section) "." counter(composite) "." counter(detail) "." counter(sub-detail) ". ";
   }


h1:hover a.anchor, h2:hover a.anchor, h3:hover a.anchor, h4:hover a.anchor, h5:hover a.anchor, h6:hover a.anchor {
   text-decoration: none; }

h1 tt, h1 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h2 tt, h2 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h3 tt, h3 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h4 tt, h4 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h5 tt, h5 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h6 tt, h6 code {
   font-size: inherit; }

h1 {
   font-size: 28px;
   color: black; }

h2 {
   font-size: 24px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
   color: black; }

h3 {
   font-size: 18px; }

h4 {
   font-size: 16px; }

h5 {
   font-size: 14px; }

h6 {
   color: #777777;
   font-size: 14px; }

/*
p, blockquote, ul, ol, dl, li, table, pre {
   margin: 15px 0; }
*/

hr {
   border: 0 none;
   color: #cccccc;
   height: 4px;
   padding: 0;
}

body > h2:first-child {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0; }
body > h1:first-child {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0; }
body > h1:first-child + h2 {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0; }
body > h3:first-child, body > h4:first-child, body > h5:first-child, body > h6:first-child {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0; }

a:first-child h1, a:first-child h2, a:first-child h3, a:first-child h4, a:first-child h5, a:first-child h6 {
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0; }

h1 p, h2 p, h3 p, h4 p, h5 p, h6 p {
   margin-top: 0; }

li p.first {
   display: inline-block; }
li {
   margin: 0; }
ul, ol {
   padding-left: 30px; }

ul :first-child, ol :first-child {
   margin-top: 0; }

dl {
   padding: 0; }
dl dt {
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: italic;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 15px 0 5px; }
dl dt:first-child {
   padding: 0; }
dl dt > :first-child {
   margin-top: 0; }
dl dt > :last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0; }
dl dd {
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 0 15px; }
dl dd > :first-child {
   margin-top: 0; }
dl dd > :last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0; }

blockquote {
   border-left: 4px solid #dddddd;
   padding: 0 15px;
   color: #777777; }
blockquote > :first-child {
   margin-top: 0; }
blockquote > :last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Copy/Paste Link Use Case Overview</h1>

<p>In order to handle links correctly in any applications that can handle HTML clipboard content on paste, the following mime type data has to be provided when a <strong>Copy</strong> command is triggered:</p>

<p>In order to handle links correctly in any applications that can handle HTML clipboard content on paste, the following mime type data has to be provided when a <strong>Copy</strong> command is triggered:</p>

<h2>Supported Mime Types</h2>

<h3>Plain Text (text/plain)</h3>

<p>For any simple <strong>Copy</strong> command as triggered by <code>CTRL+C</code> this mime type will contain the text as seen by the user, e.g. the name of the object. In case of a special <strong>Copy Link</strong> Command this will contain the <strong>global</strong> test-url of the object.</p>

<pre><code>This is the object name
</code></pre>

<pre><code>test://test.de:1643/testprod/object/12/345
</code></pre>

<h3>HTML (text/html)</h3>

<p>This behaves very similar for all <strong>Copy</strong> commands. This mime type will contain a <em>html fragment</em> with an <code>&lt;a&gt;</code>-tag brearing the <em>global</em> test-url, the name of the object and the tooltip:</p>

<pre><code>&lt;a href="test:://test.de:1643/testprod/object/12/345" title="This is the tooltip"&gt;This is an object&lt;/a&gt;
</code></pre>

<h3>Uri-List (text/uri-list)</h3>

<p>A list of global test-urls prependend by the object name in a comment line:</p>

<pre><code># Name of object 1
test://test.de:1643/testprod/object/123/5678
# Object 2
test://...
</code></pre>

<p>
<h3>EIS-List (application/test-eis-list)</h3>
<p>
A list of EIS-String that correspond to <strong>local</strong> test-urls. Whenever data is pasted inside test, the eis-list mime type is preferred. The contained data is just a list of eis:</p>

<pre><code>/object/12/345
/object/1/26
...
</code></pre>
</p>

<p>
<h2>This is a title</h2>
This is the text
<br>that should not have a 
<br> break page
</p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Context </th>
            <th> Command </th>
            <th> text/plain </th>
            <th> text/html </th>
            <th> text/uri-list </th>
            <th> eis-list </th>
            <th> Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1. Tree View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy</strong></td>
            <td>Object Name</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Text Editor Paste gives in object name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Text Editor Paste gives test-URL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Create-Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td> Like (b) but link will open a new object (create)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. Navigation Sidebar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy</strong></td>
            <td>Object Name</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS if appropriate</td>
            <td>The navigation sidebar can contain any url so if an URL is store this will be used as is. For object eis the behavior is like 1. a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Object Detail View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Plain link to open the object</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>The link to open the object also contains layout settings of the current view</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. Report Quick View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Plain link to open the report</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>The link to open the report also contains layout settings of the current view and report parameter values.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4. Report Object</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.b)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5. Embedded Report Toolbar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.b)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1. Tree View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy</strong></td>
            <td>Object Name</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Text Editor Paste gives in object name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Text Editor Paste gives test-URL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Create-Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td> Like (b) but link will open a new object (create)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. Navigation Sidebar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy</strong></td>
            <td>Object Name</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS if appropriate</td>
            <td>The navigation sidebar can contain any url so if an URL is store this will be used as is. For object eis the behavior is like 1. a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Object Detail View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Plain link to open the object</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>The link to open the object also contains layout settings of the current view</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. Report Quick View</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>Plain link to open the report</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>The link to open the report also contains layout settings of the current view and report parameter values.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4. Report Object</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.b)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5. Embedded Report Toolbar</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>a)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b)  </td>
            <td><strong>Copy Link with Layout</strong></td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>Global HTML Link</td>
            <td>Global test-URL</td>
            <td>(Local) EIS</td>
            <td>see 3.b)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Other related issues</h2>

<h3>Inconsistent Fonts and Font Sizes are used when links are pasted into MS Word</h3>

<ul>
<li>If &lsquo;Copy&rsquo;, &lsquo;Copy Object Url&rsquo; or &lsquo;Copy Create-Object-Url&rsquo; in the context menu of the tree view is used and the link is pasted into MS Word by Ctrl+V, the font &lsquo;MS Shell Dlg 2&rsquo; with size 8,5 is used.</li>
<li>Links that are copied from the navigation bar are also pasted with font &lsquo;MS Shell Dlg 2&rsquo; with size 8,5 into MS Word</li>
<li>Expected: The link is pasted into MS Word with the font that is used as standard in the Word template.</li>
</ul>


<h3>Rename &lsquo;Copy Object Url&rsquo; and &lsquo;Copy Create-Object-URL&rsquo;</h3>

<p>Both commands in the context menu for objects in the structure tree should be renamed for consistency.</p>

<ul>
<li>&lsquo;Copy Object Url&rsquo; should be renamed to &lsquo;Copy Object Link&rsquo;</li>
<li>&lsquo;Copy Create-Object-Url&rsquo; should be renamed to &lsquo;Copy Create-Object-Link&rsquo;</li>
</ul>


<h2>Additional Notes</h2>

<p>The German translations must also be renamed.</p>
<h1>Copy/Paste Link Use Case Overview</h1>

<p>In order to handle links correctly in any applications that can handle HTML clipboard content on paste, the following mime type data has to be provided when a <strong>Copy</strong> command is triggered:</p>

<h2>Supported Mime Types</h2>

<h3>Plain Text (text/plain)</h3>

<p>For any simple <strong>Copy</strong> command as triggered by <code>CTRL+C</code> this mime type will contain the text as seen by the user, e.g. the name of the object. In case of a special <strong>Copy Link</strong> Command this will contain the <strong>global</strong> test-url of the object.</p>

<pre><code>This is the object name
</code></pre>

<p>or</p>

<pre><code>test://test.de:1643/testprod/object/12/345
</code></pre>

<h3>HTML (text/html)</h3>

<p>This behaves very similar for all <strong>Copy</strong> commands. This mime type will contain a <em>html fragment</em> with an <code>&lt;a&gt;</code>-tag brearing the <em>global</em> test-url, the name of the object and the tooltip:</p>

<pre><code>&lt;a href="test:://test.de:1643/testprod/object/12/345" title="This is the tooltip"&gt;This is an object&lt;/a&gt;
</code></pre>

<h3>Uri-List (text/uri-list)</h3>

<p>A list of global test-urls prependend by the object name in a comment line:</p>

<pre><code># Name of object 1
test://test.de:1643/testprod/object/123/5678
# Object 2
test://...
</code></pre>

<h3>EIS-List (application/test-eis-list)</h3>

<p>A list of EIS-String that correspond to <strong>local</strong> test-urls. Whenever data is pasted inside test, the eis-list mime type is preferred. The contained data is just a list of eis:</p>

<pre><code>/object/12/345
/object/1/26
...
</code></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

I use IE10 as Chrome and Firefox actually have some problems with `page-break-*` and `orphans / widows`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The page-break-avoid applied to the table tells the formatting engine to not break the page inside the table. You should note that most formatters do not "go backward" and attempt to do things again, they are "go forward" engines.

So, you have page-break-avoid set on the whole table. That table is about 2.5 physical pages long.

First, the formatter tries to fit it in the current page. Of course it can't as it is longer than a page. So it throws that blank page and tries again. And again, of course it can't as it does not fit on that page.

So it creates a new blank page, places the header and starts to put down rows. BUT you have another rule -- `page-break-after="avoid"` on rows. So it can't break the page after the row so it starts putting rows in memory and ... poof. Of course they do not fit on the page as there are more rows than the page is long.

So it gives up and then places your table on that next page and breaks that condition.

You have created a hugely over-contrained set of rules.

It's not clear what you actually want as you cannot say -- I do not want a table to break inside of it and I want all the rows kept together (those are both of the rules you stated) AND then give it a table that is 2.5 pages long.

I would also note that this is a bit scary:

```
p { orphans: 5; widows: 5; page-break-after: avoid; page-break-before: avoid; }
```

What that means is keep at least 10 lines together in any p tag, never break a page before it and never after it. So literally you are saying that if you had 10 p tags in a row, none with more than 10 lines (5 orphans and 5 widows) you will hit the same condition again. It could not break inside it, before it or after it.

Now, your comment below:

> But this is a must for us (my company). The table header must be visible in all the pages.

You must mean on all pages on which the table is placed, not all the pages. And the constraints to keep a table all together (page-break-inside="avoid" on table) or to keep all the rows in a table together (page-break-after="avoid" on row) have nothing to do with that. Table headers will appear on each page the table is on. As long as they are in a table-header.

Removing all those constraints -- you see the table headers are fine and no blank pages. So remove:

- `page-break-inside="avoid"` on `table`
- `page-break-after="avoid"` on `tr`
- (and I would never have that set of rules on `p`)

[image]

Comment: But this is a must for us (my company). The table header **must** be visible in all the pages.

Comment: page-break-avoid inside is not doing that. It is saying -- do everything you can to keep this table on a single page. So what is happening is that ... it tries to fit the whole table on the page, can't ... so throws a blank page and starts creating the table. It puts the header down and tries to keep all those rows together in the table and can't because it doesn;t fit --- so it throws another page and gives up on the keep. So you get blank page, page with only a header and the pages with the table broken anyway.