# Forcing a page break only when necessary during print

Tags: html, css, printing

I am currently trying to avoid a page break in the middle of a div.  I would like it to break only if the page break occurs in the middle of the div.  However I have tried page-break-inside: avoid and it does nothing.  I can not force a page break before the div because I don't know how long the page will be.  Any help or another idea would be nice.

Here is the dive I am trying to avoid a page break in:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
        <h2 style="height:18px;">
            <span>
                <div style="width:52%; float:left;">**Delinquency Notice** as of 12/31/13</div>
                <div style="width:48%; float:left;">Recent Account History</div>
                <div styly="clear:both;"/>
            </span>
        </h2>
        <div>
            <div class="leftColumn">
                <div class="small_padding">
                    <span class="bold_text">
                        You are late on your mortgage payments.
                    </span>
                    As of 4/17/2015, you are 106 days late on your mortgage payments. 
                    Failure to bring your loan current may result in fees and 
                    foreclosure -- the loss of your home.
                    <div class="small_top_padding">
                        If you are experiencing financial difficulty, HUD (U.S. Dept 
                        of Housing and Urban Development) approved counseling agents 
                        are available to provide mortgage and foreclosure counseling 
                        assistance. Refer to the HUD disclosure section on the 
                        statement front for contact information.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightColumn">
                <div class="recent_history_body">
                    <ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
                        <li>Payment due 12/01/2014: Fully paid on 11/30/2014</li>
                        <li>Payment due 1/01/2015: Unpaid balance of $1,290.02</li>
                        <li>Payment due 2/01/2015: Fully paid on 1/31/2015</li>
                        <li>Payment due 3/01/2015: Fully paid on 2/28/2015</li>
                        <li>Payment due 4/01/2015: Fully paid on 3/17/2015</li>
                        <li>Current payment due 5/01/2015: $1,290.02</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="recent_history_total">
                        Total: $6,495.86 due. You must pay this amount to bring your loan current.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a screen shot of the print in google chrome.

[image: Printing line break]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terns out that embedding divs are not supported for page-break-inside:avoid.  In order to accomplish what I was trying to do, I needed to convert my html to a table and surround it with a single div.  This also works on FF(38.0.5), IE(11), and Chrome(43.0.2357.130 m)

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
   <table style="width:100%;">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td style="width:400px;">
                 <h2>**Delinquency Notice** as of 12/31/13</h2>
            </td>
            <td style="width:400px;">
                 <h2>Recent Account History</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="padding"><b>You are late on your mortgage payments.</b> 
                    As of 4/17/2015, you are 106 days late on your mortgage payments. 
                    Failure to bring your loan current may result in fees and 
                    foreclosure -- the loss of your home.<br/><br/>If you are experiencing financial difficulty, HUD
                    (U.S. Dept 
                    of Housing and Urban Development) approved counseling agents 
                    are available to provide mortgage and foreclosure counseling 
                    assistance. Refer to the HUD disclosure section on the 
                    statement front for contact information.
            </td>
            <td class="padding">
                <ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
                    <li>Payment due 12/01/2014: Fully paid on 11/30/2014</li>
                    <li>Payment due 1/01/2015: Unpaid balance of $1,290.02</li>
                    <li>Payment due 2/01/2015: Fully paid on 1/31/2015</li>
                    <li>Payment due 3/01/2015: Fully paid on 2/28/2015</li>
                    <li>Payment due 4/01/2015: Fully paid on 3/17/2015</li>
                    <li>Current payment due 5/01/2015: $1,290.02</li>
                </ul>
                <br/><b>Total: $6,495.86 due. You must pay this amount to bring your loan current</b></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

try with

```
@media print  
{
   div{
       page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

or this (browser dependent)

```
@media print
{
    div.pad * { 
        page-break-after:avoid;
        page-break-before:avoid;
    }
}
```

for chrome try this

```
  div.page
  {
    page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
```

For IE11 seems are problem with div try surrounding with a p

**page-break-after doesn't work with a div tag. Try a p or br tag**

```
 <p style="page-break-before: always">&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: this does not work.  I receive the same results.  Also I have <div style="page-break-inside: avoid;"> ..  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Still the same results.

Comment: Correction.  This works in firefox but not chrome or IE

Comment: In some part is useful

Comment: I  think a browser  is better then nothing. and i think this is useful for you.

Comment: 80% of my users use IE.  I will need to make sure it works for them.

Comment: Sorry, the problem with that is if there is one line on a page.  It jumps to the next game, and I am left with a whole blank page.

Comment: There is no such thing as *do not break a page inside this ... but if it is longer than a whole page, ok .. go ahead break it* command. Most formatters are only go forward. So it tries to place content by your rule ... do not break. It reaches end of page and moves all the content to the next page and goes on ... if it again reaches the end of the page it throws that page as blank and moves on and breaks your condition because it cannot be met. So if you cannot guarantee that a div will not be longer than a whole page, then it does not matter.

Comment: See this related question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756982/html-css-empty-page-only-header-page-when-printing-table/30762031#30762031

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for all your help, turns out I needed to change my html to not have embedded divs.  Once I converted it to a table, everything worked.  I am still up-voting your for all your help.